# RSA Algorithm - known n how to get p & q

Tags: c, rsa

i have got a public key with (e,n) a encrypted data and have to get the plain text via RSA and that all in C!

first of all i want to know how to find out what my p and q are? i know they have to be prime numbers and p<>q!

Comment: It is believed to be difficult to obtain p and q from n, and there is no publicly known way to do it in a feasible amount of computer time for large n in general. The security of the RSA algorithm depends upon this.

Comment: yea, Eric i know! but my e is 17 and n 3233 so not so big! and i have to calculate d, the private key. d= e^(-1)mod(p-1)(q-1) Any idea how to get d? written in c, please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, factor n. This is not hard; since sqrt(3233) is 56.8…, you only need to test prime numbers up to that. That will give you p and q. Use those to calculate (p-1)•(q-1).

Then find the multiplicative inverse of 17 modulo (p-1)•(q-1) using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). You do not need C code for that; I did it by hand. (The algorithm gives a negative result. You can either use that for d or add (p-1)•(q-1) to give a positive value that works as well.)